# Python merging doc files into 1 doc file

Tags: python, merge, doc

In Python on Linux I would like to merge several .doc files into 1 .doc file? (The .doc file will be open in Windows machines). I have searched on internet but I don't find useful information.

I know that this feature is working for PDF in GhostScript, but now it needs also working for doc files.

Has somebody suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: Was my answer correct? If so would you mind marking it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx which can help with reading/writing msft doc files. Once you have that working its just a simple read and append program.

Answer (score 0):

You can open and read contents of each files and write them in a separate file. You can File I/O functions.