# How to merge multiple DOC files into one with Python/console?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, ms-word, openoffice-writer

I am on Ubuntu environment working with a Python/Django Scrapy project.

There are a few scraped files in `.doc` format, which I want to merge (or more precisely 'append') together, i.e. put the content of second `.doc` at the end of the first one, etc., resulting in one single `.doc` file.

What is the programmatic way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem - I found the [`python-docx`](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) package suits my purpose, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363207/python-merging-doc-files-into-1-doc-file).